# Normal derivative of a sheet current

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, potential, vector-fields

Let's say we have a closed surface $\Gamma$ with a local unit normal vector $\mathbf{n}$, where a surface current (electric surface current) $\mathbf{J}_s$ lies on $\Gamma$.

The normal derivative (derivative along $\mathbf{n}$) is defined as $\partial_n = \mathbf{(n} \cdot \nabla)$.

Let's define $\mathbf{J}_s = \mathbf{K}_s\delta_s$, where $\mathbf{K}_s$ is a vector tangent to the surface (and it is continuous in space), and $\delta_S$ is the surface-dirac, defined as $\delta_S = \delta(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{R})$. $\mathbf{r}$ is the vector position and $\mathbf{R}$ is the surface parameterization for $\Gamma$.

Is $\partial_n \mathbf{K}_s = 0$ satisfied by any $\mathbf{K}_s$?

I was just thinking that $\mathbf{K}_s$ only depend on surface variables (the variables that parameterize $\Gamma$).

I made the analogy with a sphere, but obviously for a sphere $\partial_n = \partial_r$ so it would only mean that $\mathbf{K}_s$ does not vary with $r$. The latter makes sense since $\mathbf{K}_s$ on a sphere would be fixed at a constant $r$.

Same thing for a current on the $xy$-plane, we would only need $\mathbf{K}_s = \mathbf{K}_s(x,y)$ to satisfy $\partial_n \mathbf{K}_s = 0$.

Does the constraint $\partial_n \mathbf{K}_s = 0$ make sense for a surface/sheet current?

Answer (score 0):

Sheet current is typically only defined on the surface $S\subset\mathbb R^3$. We can't speak of the normal derivative of this function because you would need to "step outside" $S$ to evaluate it.

We can consider ways to define the sheet current $\bf K$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that it has the correct value on $S$. If we insist that $\bf K$ be zero outside $S$, then the derivative does not exist. If we allow $\bf K$ to be non-zero outside $S$, then there is no unique function $\bf K$ that satisfies these conditions, and functions that do satisfy them can have different normal derivatives on $S$ (which may be non-zero), so there is no unique normal derivative on $S$. In summary, it doesn't really make sense to say $\partial_n \mathbf K = 0$ in general. However, if $S$ is sufficiently smooth and does not self-intersect, I think it should always be possible to extend $\mathbf K$ from $S$ to $\mathbb R^3$ such that $\partial_n \mathbf K = 0$ on $S$.

If you need to deal with a current distribution on $\mathbf R^3$, the usual approach is to use the current density $\mathbf J$, i.e. normal current per unit area. This goes to infinity on $S$ for a sheet current, but it can still be conveniently expressed using delta functions. Consider the simple example of a sheet of current of magnitude $K$ in the xy-plane, flowing in the x-direction. The equation for current density is
$$ \mathbf J = K\delta(z)\bf x$$
$$\partial_n\mathbf J = \partial_z\mathbf J = K\delta'(z) \bf x.$$

This involves a [derivative of the delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Derivatives_of_the_Dirac_delta_function), which is only zero outside the sheet, or if the sheet current is zero. The same is true for sheet currents on more general surfaces.